# How can I apply any font face in vs code on the text written in punjabi language?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded the font of my choice for punjabi language. But if I type in english only then it is giving me the required output, and if I write text in punjabi(gurmukhi) then it is showing me the output without applying the mentioned font face, i.e. showing the text as it is in punjabi(gurmukhi). Have tried this in HTML and CSS also but none is working....

Here is the HTML code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prabhki font</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: myfont;
            src: url(Prabhki.ttf);
        }
        h3{
            font-family: myfont !important;
        }
        h1{
            font-family: "Prabhki";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>ਪੰਜਾਬੀ <br> panjabi</h3>
    <h1>ਪੰਜਾਬੀ <br> panjabi</h1>
</body>
</html>

[![Output on chrome][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXosP.png
```

Comment: the `font` tag is deprecated for a long time (many years), use CSS to select a different font, you talk about `show` but does not describe where this `show` is: editor or browser, do you change VSC settings or do you only modify the HTML

Comment: Are you sure the font supports punjabi?

Comment: You might need to download or add the link to that specific font. Try to embed the font in your html: https://fonts.google.com/?subset=gurmukhi

Comment: @rioV8 Now see the output in browser also. Didn't change any VSC setting but only modify the HTML part..... including some CSS this time

Comment: what is the `</h1>` doing on line 23

Comment: @rioV8 now see.... corrected the code

Comment: I still don't know what is incorrect rendered in Chrome? Don't show images of your code, copy the code directly to the question using triple backtick. Comment the chrome picture with what is incorrectly rendered, Don't use the `font` tag, what is its purpose anyway. HTML5 does not have a `font` tag defined.